# Why do I get 2 callbacks in GLFW3 - OpenGL

Tags: glfw, opengl-3

I am using GLFW3 for window handling of OpenGL3.3+. Everything works correctly, however I do not understand why it prints "A pressed" two times whenever I press my A key. In particular I want it to be printed just once for 1 keypress A.

```
static void My_Key_Callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if( key == 'A' )
    {
        std::cout<< "A pressed\n";
        return;
    }
}


int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    // --1-- Initialise GLFW
    if( glfwInit() == false )
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize GLFW3\nQuiting....\n";
        exit(1);
    }


    // --2-- Create Window
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4); // 4x antialiasing
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // We want OpenGL 3.3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); //We don't want the old OpenGL

    GLFWwindow * window=NULL;
    window = glfwCreateWindow( 400, 400, "hello", NULL, NULL );
    if( window == NULL )
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create glfw window\nQuiting....\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(1);
    }

    // --3-- Make current context
    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );


// 
// .
// . Normal OpenGL code goes here
// .
//

    // set call back
    glfwSetKeyCallback( window, My_Key_Callback);

    // --5-- Main loop
    glfwSetInputMode( window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE );
    glClearColor(0,0,.4,0);



    do
    {


        ////// Some more OpenGL code here 

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36); 


        // swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers( window );
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    while( glfwWindowShouldClose(window)==false );



}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a single keyboard event callback in GLFW3 which handles `GLFW_RELEASE` events as well:

[typedef void(* GLFWkeyfun)(GLFWwindow *, int, int, int, int)](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html#ga592dd1919f8a1dc7576b13cdd8b7b695)

The 4th argument is `action`: `GLFW_PRESS, GLFW_RELEASE or GLFW_REPEAT.`
You can ignore the key release event, e.g.,

```
if (action == GLFW_RELEASE)
    return;

// ... handle PRESS, REPEAT of a key...
```

Answer (score 1):

The way GLFW is designed, the callback function is called at each event, such as key pressed or key released. To ignore the key release event, have your code surrounded by a conditional statement, as in  "if (action != GLFW_RELEASE)":

```
void keyCallback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {

    std::cout << "Key pressed, action! " << key << ", " << action << std::endl;

    if (action != GLFW_RELEASE) {       // avoid double updates

    switch (key) {
        case GLFW_KEY_W: camZ -= 0.5f; break;
        case GLFW_KEY_S: camZ += 0.5f; break;

        case GLFW_KEY_A: camX -= 0.5f; break;
        case GLFW_KEY_D: camX += 0.5f; break;

        case GLFW_KEY_Z: camY -= 0.5f; break;
        case GLFW_KEY_X: camY += 0.5f; break;

        case GLFW_KEY_E: yaw -= 0.5f; break;        // around y axis
        case GLFW_KEY_R: yaw += 0.5f; break;

        case GLFW_KEY_UP: pitch -= 0.5f; break;     // around x axis
        case GLFW_KEY_DOWN: pitch += 0.5f; break;

        case GLFW_KEY_LEFT: roll -= 0.5f; break;    // around z axis
        case GLFW_KEY_RIGHT: roll += 0.5f; break;

        case GLFW_KEY_SPACE:
            scaleAmount = 1.0; theta = 0.5;
            yaw = 0.0; pitch = 0.5; roll = 0.0;
            camX = 0.0; camY = 0.0; camZ = 0.0;
            break;
        }

        print(Model);
    }
}
```